# Select oldest timestamp in MySQL when grouping rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT product,
       SUM(price) AS revenue,
       COUNT(*)   AS sales,
       timestamp
FROM   payments
WHERE  status = 'Completed'
        OR status = 'Pending'
        OR status = 'Canceled_Reversal'
GROUP  BY product
```

Everything is working as it should, except for the `timestamp` column.

That column shows the date/time when a payment was received.  I'm wanting it to show the last date that each product was purchased.  Right now it appears to show the oldest no matter what I change...

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results . Cheers!

Comment: I can't see how the accepted answer fulfils the brief but hey, it's your party

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting `MAX(timestamp)` as in the following. You should be using an aggregate function such as `SUM`, `COUNT` or `MAX` for every column selected that is *not* mentioned in a `GROUP BY` clause anyway or else the query becomes suspect or even possibly illegal depending on MySql *only_full_group_by* option. In your case it is just selecting `timestamp` from an arbitrary row.

```
SELECT product,
       SUM(price) AS revenue,
       COUNT(*)   AS sales,
       MAX(timestamp) as timestamp
FROM   payments
WHERE  status = 'Completed'
        OR status = 'Pending'
        OR status = 'Canceled_Reversal'
GROUP  BY product
```